# I have THREE.Geometry() linked list for face/vertex

Tags: three.js

I have  THREE.Geometry() instance , i have access to vertex and faces. How can i get linked list for vertex or faces. I need to get the adjacent nodes / faces from the geometry object.

Comment: Please, read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76 , Yes vertices and faces (array of Face3) are arrays . I need linked list so that I can query adjustency . I am looking for solution to find a faces or vertices in a given area of circle on the surface (mesh) . I found single linked list called   VertexNode data structure in threejs library but did not find any example how the use that .